# Create stored procedure with mutliple output categories in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am working in **MySQL Workbench** and using the following SQL sample data. https://www.databasestar.com/sample-database-superheroes/

My diagram is attached at the bottom.

How do I create a stored procedure where you input the name of a superhero (e.g. Firebird) and get which specific fire-themed superpower they have?

So far, my code looks like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Elemental_Heroes;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Elemental_Heroes(
IN HeroName VARCHAR(250),
OUT ElementalCat VARCHAR(250))
BEGIN
    DECLARE credit DECIMAL DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT 
    s.id,
    s.superhero_name,
    sp.power_name
        FROM superhero s
            LEFT JOIN hero_power hp ON s.id = hp.hero_id
            LEFT JOIN superpower sp ON hp.power_id = sp.id
                WHERE sp.id IN (56,79,90,104,140) AND s.superhero_name = HeroName
                    GROUP BY s.id, s.superhero_name, sp.power_name;

    IF
    ELSE
    
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL Elemental_Heroes(Firebird);
```

Where the `IF ELSE` part is just a placeholder for the conditional statements I know must eventually be there. The entire elect part (minus the `s.superhero_name = HeroName`) runs as desired.

I'm also wondering if there's any way for the output to be multiple categories. Because Firebird has Fire Control, Fire Resistance, and Heat Resistance and I would like all three categories to be the output when I call `Elemental_Heroes(Firebird)`.

[image]

Comment: I do not see the question... and I do not see the place in code where the value is assigned to the output parameter.

Comment: @Akina I've edited the question - I hope it is clearer now. As for assigning the output parameter: that is part of what I'm hoping to get help with.

Comment: *As for assigning the output parameter: that is part of what I'm hoping to get help with.* `ElementalCat` is common local variable and may be assigned like any other local variable - using SET or SELECT INTO. If you need to return more than one value in one variable then you must serialize these values into one value (CSV, JSON, etc.). Then retrieve/parse in outer code.

Comment: *I would like all three categories to be the output when I call `Elemental_Heroes(Firebird)`.* (1) Your SP have 2 parameters - so you must provide 2 parameters to it. (2) Provided value is string literal, and it must be enclosed with quote chars. Finally: `CALL Elemental_Heroes(Firebird, @output); SELECT @output;`

Answer (score 1):

A sample.

Create source data

```
CREATE TABLE main
SELECT 1 id, 'Name 1' name UNION SELECT 2, 'Name 2' UNION SELECT 3, 'Name 3';
CREATE TABLE slave
SELECT 1 id, 1 val UNION SELECT 1, 2 UNION SELECT 2, 3 UNION 
  SELECT 2, 1 UNION SELECT 3, 2 UNION SELECT 3, 3;
```

Create stored procedure which retrieves `name`s list by provided `val` value

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_id_by_val (IN in_val INT, OUT out_names_list TEXT)
BEGIN
  SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(name) INTO out_names_list 
  FROM main
  JOIN slave USING (id)
  WHERE slave.val = in_val;
END
```

SP queries the names by the value provided in `in_val` input parameter and saves found values into `out_names_list` output parameter

Using SP

```
CALL get_id_by_val(3, @output);
-- retrieve the list as solid JSON array
SELECT @output;
-- retrieve the same in separate rows
SELECT name FROM JSON_TABLE(@output, '$[*]' COLUMNS (name VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')) jsontable
```

In CALL we provide criteria value for `in_val` parameter and use user-defined variable `@output` as a place where the output will be placed into.

Solid JSON array output

| @output |
| --- |
| ["Name 2", "Name 3"] |

Output parsed to separate values

| name |
| --- |
| Name 2 |
| Name 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zJvZRAeA)

Comment: PS. In my sample the criteria value is numeric and does not need in enclosing with single quote chars.